# Custom Comparator function using iterators

Tags: c++, sorting, iterator, comparator

I have a 2D jagged vector (each row may be of different size) and a vector which represents the cost of the path in the particular row of the 2D jagged vector.

Lets call the 2D jagged vector as `allpaths` and the cost vector as `cost`. As mentioned cost[i] is the cost of the path given by allpaths[i]. `allpaths[i]` represents a vector of vertices in the path.

I want to sort `allpaths` on basis of their cost. If the cost is equal, I want to sort it on the basis of the number of vertices (size of the vector).

To do this, I have first made a vector of pairs and then sorted it. **To save memory, the second argument of the pair is an iterator instead of the whole vector** :

```
vector <pair<int, vector<string>::iterator>> V;
for(int i=0; i <allpaths.size(); i++)
    V.push_back(make_pair(cost[i], allpaths[i].begin()));
sort(V.begin(), V.end(), cmp);
```

The custom comparator function is as follows:

```
bool cmp(const pair<int, vector<string>::iterator> A, const pair<int, vector<string>::iterator> B)
{
    if(A.first == B.first)
        return *(A.second).size() < *(B.second).size();
    return A.first < B.first;
}
```

This returns a ton of compiler error. What is the correct way to do this? 
I think the error is here: `*(A.second).size() < *(B.second).size()`

How does one dereference an iterator to a 1D vector?

The code snippet is [here](https://ideone.com/KiiAO2)

Comment: You know that std::vector has specialized std::swap, right? A sorting algorithm will be able to swap two std::vector-s in O(1) time. You don't need to optimize by keeping, presumabely, all data in a single big vector and then holding iterators in your map.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a self-contained piece of code, so I cannot solve all your problems. However, I see some problems, as follows:

- If you have a `std::vector<T>` with `T = std::pair<int, std::vector<int>::iterator>` then your comparator should take two elements of `const T&`. Instead, you take the whole `std::vector<T>`. That will not work.
- `std::vector<int>::iterator` has no member function `size()`. As a result you cannot have `A.second->size()` and `B.second->size()`. You really need an `std::vector` here, not just an iterator. An iterator knows only about the element it is pointing to, not the whole vector.

However, as I explained in the comment, `std::vector` has a specialised `swap` which will work in constant time. The sorting algorithm will use that `swap` inside. So, you really do not need to replace an `std::vector` with an iterator (or a pointer to the vector).

What usually happens under the hood is that `std::vector` object itself is just a pointer to some dynamically allocated array (and an info about it's size). `std::swap` will just swap the pointer value (and size info), without copying the actual contents of the array.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. I have corrected them. I have added a code snippet. 
I am not sure I understand how the swap option would work in a comparator. Would you please show with an example or give references where I could read up?

Comment: Oh, you are seriously changing the code. i.e. `std::vector<int>` is now `std::vector<string>`. Please don't do that. That makes our answers irrelevant, obsolete and make them look stupid.

Comment: To answer your question - the comparator is *not* using `std::swap`. The swap is used by the sorting algorithm.

Comment: Apologies for making the change. I made the change so that the post is consistent with the code snippet I have put. I have made the allpath vector of string (from integer) to avoid confusion with the cost vector which is of integers. Would request you to please make the change in the answer too. 

I am still unable to grasp your solution with the swap. I would request for an example or some reference. How do I implement it?

Comment: I don't have any solution with swap. I am telling you that the `std::sort` you are using is most likely going to use swap when possible, so that you don't move entire vectors around. As a result you do not need to optimize it further with mere iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Your cmp function should accept parameters which are members of your vector, not the type of the vector itself. That is: `pair<int, vector<int>::iterator>`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have corrected the error. But the problem still persists.